# How to update the method definition in the optimized way utilizing less memory and be more efficient and fast?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, linq, c#-4.0

Code:

```
public void TestCollection(IEnumerable<ITestItem> testItems)
{
    SendOrPostCallback callback = delegate
    {
        foreach (var testItem in testItems.ToArray())
        {
            TestItemGroup tests;
            if (this.TryTestControls(testItem, out tests))
            {
                int count = 0;
                foreach (var header in gridViewHeadersCollections)
                {
                    if (!(tests[count].DisplayText == header))
                    {
                        TestItem TI = new TestItem();
                        ITestCtrlItem IT = TI;
                        tests.TestItems.Insert(count, IT);
                        break;
                    }
                    count++;
                }
                continue;
            }

            this.testList.TestGroups.Add(
                new TestItemGroup(this.testList.DataProvider.GetTestGroup(testItem)));
        }
    };

    this.testList.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, callback, null);
}
```

> ITestItem is an Interface
>
> testItem is a local variable
>
> TestItemGroup is a class
>
> TryTestControls is a boolean method
>
> gridViewHeadersCollections is ICollection
>
> tests is a local variable
>
> DisplayText is a string
>
> TestItem is a class
>
> ITestCtrlItem is an interface
>
> TestItems is a IList
>
> GetTestGroup is a method

How to update the method definition in the optimized way utilizing less memory and be more efficient and fast?

Comment: Question should belong to [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use parallel task for this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608(v=vs.110).aspx